# Only show light from an otherwise transparent plane

Tags: three.js, mapbox-gl-js

Similar to [ShadowMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=shadowm#api/en/materials/ShadowMaterial), is there a material that only receives light but is otherwise fully transparent?
If such does not or should not exist - is there a way to cast a spotlight on an otherwise transparent plane?

The use case for this is to simulate a spotlight on a Mapbox map with mapbox gl custom (three.js) layers

Comment: So you want the specular effect of the light without the plane having any color? You may need to write a custom shader material for this. The idea being, you would calculate the fragment as if it were a regular blending of the light with whatever color is underneath it (maybe default to black?), setting the alpha value of the fragment based on the gradient of the background-to-light colors (background = full transparent, light color = full opaque).

Comment: Thanks @TheJim01 - do you have an example that I could look at?